# nm-applet knows secrets that nmcli does not

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

When I connect to a wifi network automatically or by choosing it with nm-applet, and assuming I've successfully connected with WPA2 previously, the connection is fine.

If I connect by typing `nmcli device wifi connect network-name`, then I'm asked for the password (via nm's dialog popup box), at which point the connection succeeds.

Is there a way I can tell nmcli about the secrets that nm-applet clearly knows?

[This concerns ubuntu 17.04 but appears to be the case since ubuntu 16.04 at least.]

Answer (score 0):

Use `nmcli con up network-name`.

The command `nmcli device wifi connect network-name` tries to create a connection, rather than using the stored data for the old one.